# Aid a Github noob - Change my latest release

Tags: github

First of all, I'm a massive github noob. I basically use it as a stable place to host downloads. However, one thing has been bugging me. I currently have two releases, 1.0 and 2.0 . For some reason I can't figure out, it's calling 1.0 the latest release...
[image: The weird version-ing of github...]

And of course, here's a link: https://github.com/darthmorf/T-Backup

Thanks for your help.

-darthmorf

Comment: Github releases are tags on git commits, so since you haven't committed any code, the hashes (b5c6b35) are the same and it's not possible for github to decide which release is newer.

Comment: Is there a way for me to tell it which is newer? Or a guide to upload the VS .sln, and therefore commit some code?

Comment: You may be able to just update the Readme file and commit it.  Then do a new release based on that commit.

Comment: Thanks very much, this worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kateract answered this in the comments. I'm going to post what he said here so it can be marked as an answer:

> Github releases are tags on git commits, so since you haven't
>   committed any code, the hashes (b5c6b35) are the same and it's not
>   possible for github to decide which release is newer. You may be able
>   to just update the Readme file and commit it. Then do a new release
>   based on that commit.

Answer (score 0):

Github won't mark a tag as a "Release" until you actively set as one on the GitHub website. Up at the top of your Releases page, you should see a "Draft New Release" button. If you click that, select your 2.0 tag, and hit Publish, it should now display it as a release for you.

You can enter a title / description if you wish, but feel free to just leave them blank - if you do, GitHub will use the Tag name and text instead.

--
Hope this helps :)

Comment: That's how I published those two releases. If I do what you've suggested, it says 'Duplicate tag name'.